# anchors is not working as expected

Tags: html, anchor

I dont know why simple html is not working

```
<a target="_blank" data-index="1"
   href="http://localhost:88/solo/#1"
   class="active">click</a>
```

it should open a new window and go to the link , but strange its when I click nothing happens

thanks in advance

Comment: You have popup blocker? Or JS is binded and prevents default action?

Comment: Seems to work fine, do you possibly have any javascript blocking the action?

Comment: worked - [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/IVIJiXis/1/edit)

Comment: Works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/k3ZaV/ Are you expecting a new window? In most modern browsers a new window is a new tab.

Comment: Are you by anychance on the same URL as the one you are linking to? `http://localhost:88/solo/#1`

Comment: You have some other error could you please post more html markup???? This is working fine in jsFiddle

Comment: Valdas I didn't set any popup blocker , I dont think any blocking action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/45hVh/)

Code is working perfectly:

```
<a target="_blank" data-index="1" href="http://localhost:88/solo/#1" class="active">click</a>
```

Please check your system security and add your site url to safe site for allow popup.
Or thier might be some JavaScript that bind an event to this anchor tag click and stopping its default action execution by:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

or by returning false.

Comment: how to detect what is preventing ?

Comment: thanks worked , I searched in the js e.preventDefault(); and deleted , its worked